# whats wrong with this? submit.CommandText = sql?

Tags: compiler-errors

Dim sql As String

```
sql = "insert into transactions (`transid`) values('" + Text1.Text + "')"
sql = sql & "; insert into customer (`custid`) values('" + Text2.Text + "')"
sql = sql & "; insert into customer (`custname`) values('" + Text3.Text + "')"
sql = sql & "; insert into transactions (`custid`) values('" + Text2.Text + "')"
sql = sql & "; insert into transactions (`serviceid`) values('" + Combo1.Text + "')"
sql = sql & "; insert into transactions (`empid`) values('" + Combo2.Text + "')"
 submit.CommandText = sql
```

what should I put in submit.CommandText = sql, i can't understand this part. please help me guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can simplify this into something like:

```
sql = "insert into transactions(transid, custid, serviceid, empid) _
 values('" + Text1.Text + "','" + Text2.Text + "', '" + Combo1.Text + "', '" + Combo2.Text "');"
sql = sql + " insert into customer(custid, custname) values('" + Text2.Text + "', '" + Text3.Text + "');"
```